# Check ViewContext.RouteData.Values to see if parameter exists

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

How can I check to see if Values contains a parameter before assigning it to a variable?

null checks do not seem to work

```
    var offeringId;
    if (@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["offeringId"] == null) {
        offeringId = null;
    } else {
        offeringId = @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["offeringId"];
    }

    //the above line translates to the code below in the console when executed. 
    //If the value doesn't exist, nothing is displayed on the left side of the = operator.

    var offeringId;
    if ( == null) {
        offeringId = null;
    } else {
        offeringId = ;
    }
```

Comment: You should move `var tempvalue = @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["offeringId"]`

Comment: remove @ before `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["offeringId"]`. Also, if the value is null then why assign it to null again?

Answer (score 0):

Do this first:

```
@{ string offeringValue = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["offeringId"] ?? "null";}
```

Then assign `offeringId` like this:

```
var offeringId = @offeringValue;
```

If `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["offeringId"] == null`, your script will look like this:

```
var offeringId = null;
```

`??` is the `null` coalesce operator (it will return the **first** value that is **not** `null`)